# Error while adding custom field using module: ParseError: "arch" while parsing file

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to add a custom field to Odoo 9 `res.partner` model using module. I have used scoffold command to generate the module files and added following code to models.py and views.xml.

**models/models.py**

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
class SeicoPartner(models.Model):
    _name  = 'res.partner'
    _inherit  = 'res.partner'

   no_of_ac = fields.Integer('No of AC', default=0)
   review = fields.Char('Company Review')
```

**views/views.xml**

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="res_partner_field_ac" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="no_of_ac">10</field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Upon installation of this module from Apps screen, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20160719\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 344, in create
ParseError: "arch" while parsing file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%209.0-20160719/server/openerp/addons/mymodule1/views/views.xml:4, near
<record id="res_partner_field_ac" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="no_of_ac">10</field>

        </record>
```

From the `Settings -> Database Structure -> Fields` I can see that res.partner has the `no_of_ac` field, but the field is not visible while editing any customer details.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're missing the arch field with describes the type of view (either xml or html), in most cases xml is just fine,

You're also missing the model name, the view name, so odoo doesn't know which model your view belongs to. you also have to specify the existing model form you want to over-ride and the position where you want the new field to be, in this case i used an xpath expression to display the field after the website field in the parent view, it can be anywhere you want it to be.

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="res_partner_field_ac" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
      <field name="model">res.partner</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='website']" position="after">
          <field name="no_of_ac" />
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

also you don't need to specify `_name` if you just want to extend a model and add extra fields to it, so change your model code to this

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
class SeicoPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit  = 'res.partner'

   no_of_ac = fields.Integer('No of AC', default=0)
   review = fields.Char('Company Review')
```

Comment: you can't just add the field into the view: you need to declare another componento of the view to which "attach" the field

Comment: i have tried this method to resolve my error but still have the error of "Element '<field name="no_of_ac">' cannot be located in parent view"...Now tell me what should i do to resolve it.As i am new user of Odoo so need your help.

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo, I've addressed that, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a new record in `ir.ui.view` data model.

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="res_partner_field_ac" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="no_of_ac">10</field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

But you want to insert data to : `res.partner`

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="res_partner_field_ac" model="res.partner">
        <field name="name">a name here because it's required when the field type != 'contact' </field>
        <field name="no_of_ac">10</field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

NOTE :you encountered a problem because `arch` is a requrired field in`ir.ui.view` model.

Comment: I have tried it but still have the following Parse Error: "new row for relation "res_partner" violates check constraint "res_partner_check_name"

Comment: this erreur because when the name is null the type field must be 'contact'  so in your case the name is required so add    to your code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a data record you should use `res.partner` as model and define the required fields:

```
<record id="res_partner_field_ac" model="res.partner">
    <field name="no_of_ac">10</field>
    <field name="name">NEW PARTNER NAME</field>
    <!-- define required fields -->
</record>
```

To define a view, take a look at [Odoo views](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html#basic-views)